# Using `while` to repeat the process if user wants to do another operation

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I wrote the following code:

```
puts "Money to deposit:"
money_invested = gets.to_f

puts "Time in days:"
time_investment = gets.to_f

puts "Indicate interest rate:"
interest_rate = gets.to_f

investment_calculation =
money_invested * (1 + interest_rate / 100 * time_investment / 365)
puts "Your money will be: $%.2f." % investment_calculation
```

I want to ask if the user wants to perform another operation:

```
puts "Would you like to perform another operation? Indicate 'Y' or 'N'"
another.operation = gets.chomp
```

If the user says `N`, I would say something like `puts "Thanks for your time! The app will be closed in one minute`. But if the user wants to run another operation (type `Y`), I need to run all the code again. I know this can be done with `while`, but don't know exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you use `while(true)....break if (...)...end` or (my preferance) `loop do....break if (...)....end`. You could also use `until`.

Answer (score 4):

You can maintain an infinite loop, and `break` it when desired:

```
NO = %w{ n no nope negative negatory nyet }
loop do
  # all of your various questions & responses

  puts "Would you like to perform another operation? Indicate 'Y' or 'N'"
  response = gets.chomp
  break if NO.include?(response.downcase)

  # Additional code could go here, if it's appropriate
  # to perform repeated actions after user indicates
  # they don't want to quit
end

# cleanup code here
```

Comment: Your list is incomplete. You'll find more [here](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/10/ways-to-say-no/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Gee, thanks!  I'll have to remember those for my next project.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with loops yet. Could you please indicate where should I place the `loop do` and the `break if`?

Comment: See the comment that says `# all of your various questions & responses`?  That's where you put all of your current various questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable to switch between `true`/`false` based on user input. The first run it will be implicitly `true`:

```
do_loop = true
while do_loop

    puts "Money to deposit:"
    money_invested = gets.to_f

    puts "Time in days:"
    time_investment = gets.to_f

    puts "Indicate interest rate:"
    interest_rate = gets.to_f

    investment_calculation = money_invested * (1 + interest_rate/100 *     time_investment/365)
    puts "Your money will be: $%.2f." % investment_calculation

    puts "Would you like to perform another operation? Indicate 'Y' or 'N'"
    answer = gets.chomp

    # assign "true" to loop variable only if first character is 'Y' or 'y'
    do_loop = answer.size > 0 && answer.downcase[0] == 'y'
end
```